# Multiple table SQL trigger an email to update

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2, automation

Ok, much closer here for sure, but now it sends mass amounts of emails on one record update? I know I'm missing something here. First shot at cursors, so I'm guessing I've done something wrong in there? As always, Thanks for the help!!

```
create trigger eMailScheduleChange on dbo.BOOKINGS after update as

set nocount on;

Declare EmailCursor Cursor read_only for
    select r.Name as RName
    , c.Name as CName
    , i.BookingTypeId
    , i.Start
    , i.Finish
    , r.Email
from Wallchart.dbo.BOOKINGS b
inner join Wallchart.dbo.CUSTOMERS c on b.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
inner join Wallchart.dbo.RESOURCES r on b.ResourceId = r.ResourceId
inner join Inserted i on i.CustomerId = b.CustomerId
where i.BookingTypeId <> b.BookingTypeId 

Declare @Email as varchar(50)
Declare @CName as varchar(100)
Declare @Start as datetime
Declare @RName as varchar (100)
Declare @Finish as datetime
Declare @body as varchar (255)
Declare @BookingTypeId as varchar (50)

open EmailCursor
Fetch next from EmailCursor
INTO @Email, @CName, @Start, @RName, @Finish, @BookingTypeId
While @@FETCH_STATUS=0

BEGIN

    Set @body = '<Account cancelled>' + @CName + @Start + @Finish

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

@profile_name = 'SQLMail',
@recipients = @Email,
  @subject = 'Account Update',
  @body = @body

FETCH NEXT FROM EmailCursor INTO @Email, @CName, @Start, @RName, @Finish,       @BookingTypeId
SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
Close EmailCursor
Deallocate EmailCursor
```

Comment: First thing you should do is stop using " everywhere. It makes it a lot harder to read and can actually cause issues. Also, if you are going to use table aliases you should actually provide a different name or there is no point in providing an alias. That is like saying your name is Travis (aka Travis).

Comment: Now...what is your actual question here? Seems to me that if you need an email sent when the BookingTypeID changes you would create a trigger on BOOKINGS. That seems to be the table that holds BookingTypeID.

Comment: I understand, weird force of habit there. Correct, when the BookTypeId is changed, it's changed in the bookings table. However, the customer name is in the customers table and the resource name and email are in the resource table. Using a trigger, I can fire an email to myself and say it changed, but I have no idea what customer name, who the resource was, etc. So if a bookingtypeID was changed, email the resource email, customer name and bookings start.

Comment: Then the trigger can only logically belong in the BOOKINGS table right? And the time you want it to fire is when the value is changed. You want your trigger to send an email right? Why can't you simply put this query in the trigger to retrieve the values you need? There is no rule that code inside a trigger can only reference itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think perhaps you have the impression that a query in a trigger is not allowed to read data from another table. This is not the case or triggers would be fairly useless. Here is a stub of how your trigger might look. I demonstrated how to pull the information you want. From there it is simply calling sp_send_dbmail.

```
create trigger MyTrigger on dbo.BOOKINGS for update as
    set nocount on;

    select r.Name
        , c.Name
        , i.BookingTypeId
        , i.Start
        , i.Finish
        , r.Email
    from Schedule.dbo.BOOKINGS b
    inner join Wallchart.dbo.CUSTOMERS c on b.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
    inner join Schedule.dbo.RESOURCES r on b.ResourceId = r.ResourceId
    inner join Inserted i on i.SomeKeyValue = b.SomeKeyValue
    where i.BookingTypeID <> b.BookingTypeID

    --Now you can see how to capture all the information. All that is left is to call sp_send_dbmail
    --https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx
```

Comment: Thanks Sean, this is where I somewhat ended up before. Don't I have to set the variables in order to pass to sp_send_dbmail? ie 
    'Declare ATempEmail as varchar(50)
    'Set ATempEmail = ?

Comment: Yes you need to get these values into a variable. Sending emails is one of those incredibly rare times where a cursor is actually the best option.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not support direct mailing from the scripts. But you have other options.

First Create a table to capture the records that are being changed and also set a EmailFlag so that you can identify whether or not you have notified that user about the change.

The create a store procedure that will give you the list of all users that has undergone some changes but not notified by email (EmailFlag ="N" or something like that)

Now use the SSIS to create a send mail task to send the details email for all these users.

Once you have sent the email for each user, then you can update the EmailFlag as "Y" for that record. You can make the SSIS package a scheduled job in the SQL Server so that it will automatically run between certain interval.

You can use a for each loop container in SSIS so that you can send mail individually to each recipient

Please refer the following Links for more details 
[SSIS - How to configure a send mail task](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NGqRIsM_P04)

Comment: SSIS is a bit overkill here.

Comment: especially when you can call [sp_send_dbmail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx)

Comment: But I think that's better here because you can directly access the SQL database and it gives you more control over the database compared to the other languages or tools

Comment: It is like killing a mosquito with an Abrams tank.